# Selecionar mais de uma data com MultiDatesPicker + tecla shift

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

Fiz um sistema administrativo para um site de aluguel de imóveis, para marcar as datas que o imóvel já esta locado eu usei o [Multi Dates Picker](https://github.com/dubrox/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI), funcionou muito bem. Agora o cliente precisa de uma funcionalidade a mais, que realmente não estou conseguindo implementar:

Selecionar um período de datas longo usando a telcla shift do teclado. Ele segura a tecla shift do teclado, seleciona a data inicial e depois a data final e todos os dias entre essas duas datas ficam selecionados.

Alguém tem ideia?

Comment: Opa, valeu pela ajuda. Eu tinha achado essa solução no stackoverflow em inglês. O problema é que nesse está sendo usado datepicker e eu preciso suar o [multiDatesPicker](http://multidatespickr.sourceforge.net), pois no sistema tem mais algumas soluções que só o Multi Date resolve....